# Nginx: rewrite rule to redirect to https page

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I want to redirect my login page to https so that users do not inadvertently enter their credentials through the unencrypted network.  How do I do something like the below?

```
# nginx.conf
server {
  server_name example.org;
  rewrite http://*.example.org/login https://example.org/login;
}
```

This works for http://example.org/login, but it does not work for http://www.example.org/login

Rewrite rule output for

```
rewrite http://.*\.?example.org/login https://example.org/login;
```

Rewrite debug output:

```
*2 "http://.*\.?example.org/login" does not match "/login", client: XXX.XXX.XX.72, server: example.org, request: "GET /user HTTP/1.1", host: "example.org"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I deleted my original answer as it was quite a lot easier. You'll need a location block and an if for this to work, along with a catchall server domain. Structure as follows:

```
 server {
   server_name example.org;
   server_name *.example.org;
   location /login {
       if ( $scheme = http ) {
          rewrite ^ https://example.org/login last;
       }
   }
 }
```

As much as I hate using ifs in nginx coming, this time, it's necessary.

Comment: In case you don't wanna hardcode the hostname (example.org), you can use the $server_name variable (as per the [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables))